# How to code a pathfinding player in godot using A*?

Tags: path-finding, godot, gdscript

Iam nooby in godot, I have to use A* to traslate the player to the goal position, but I do not know how to start, pls help!! basically I have just 2 tiles in the tilemap, 1 of them is allowed to pass over it, I have to extract I guess the allowed tile and calculate the distance between the position player with the position goal, getting the real distance and then check cell per cell which has the lowest cost, but I do not know how to do that :c

```
func get_player_init_pos():
  var pos = map_to_world(Vector2(54,1))pos.y += half_cell_size.y
  return pos
```

```
func is_tile_vacant(pos, direction):
  var curr_tile = world_to_map(pos)
  var next_tile = get_cellv(curr_tile + direction)
  var next_tile_pos = Vector2()
  if(next_tile == 0):
   next_tile_pos = map_to_world(curr_tile + direction)
  else:next_tile_pos = pos
  return next_tile_pos
```

I have this, the first part of the code is to locate the player in the map and the second is for check the tile walls in the map

Answer (score 1):

You could roll your own path finding algorithm. However, there is little point in doing so, since Godot has a `AStar` class you can use. However, you probably don't need to use that either, because Godot has a navigation system. And that is what I'm going to suggest you to use.

First of all, you can specify both navigation and collision polygons on your tiles. You need to have the navigation polygons. Go ahead and do them.

Second you want to have a `Navigation2D` in the scene tree and have your `TileMap` as a child.

And third, you can ask the `Navigation2D` for a path with `get_simple_path`, you pass the start and end positions as arguments and you get an array of points that make up the path.

---

Since you mention A*, I'll briefly explain using the `AStar` too anyway.

First, you need to add the cells with `add_point`. It requires ids. It is a good idea to be clever with the ids so you can compute the id for a given position. For example `x * width + y` if you know the size.

So you can iterate over the tiles in your `TileMap` and call `add_point` for each one (You don't need to add cell that are not passable).

Then you need to specify the connections with `connect_points` (it takes the ids of the points as parameters).

And finally you can call `get_point_path` passing the start and end ids. Again it gives you a array of points.